# Cannot infer coder for classes annotated with @DefaultSchema

Tags: java, apache-beam

As per [Apache Beam's documentation on Schemas](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#schemas), one does not need to manually specify a coder for a type annotated with `@DefaultSchema` annotation.

However, I cannot achieve such expected behaviour.

Here's a little test code that I wrote to verify this:

```java
  public static void main(String[] args) throws CannotProvideCoderException {
    PipelineOptions pipelineOptions = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();
    pipelineOptions.setRunner(DirectRunner.class);
    Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(pipelineOptions);
    CoderRegistry coderRegistry = pipeline.getCoderRegistry();
    Coder<TemporalKey> temporalKeyCoder = coderRegistry.getCoder(TemporalKey.class);
    System.out.println(temporalKeyCoder.getClass());
  }
```

Where the `TemporalKey` is a custom Java Bean class that uses lombok for auto getter generation:

```java
@DefaultSchema(JavaBeanSchema.class)
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
public class TemporalKey {
  private final int year;
  private final int month;
  private final int day;
  private final int dayPeriodNum;

  @SchemaCreate
  public TemporalKey(int year, int month, int day, int dayPeriodNum) {
    this.year = year;
    this.month = month;
    this.day = day;
    this.dayPeriodNum = dayPeriodNum;
  }
}
```

Running the code gives me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.CannotProvideCoderException: Unable to provide a Coder for com.example.model.TemporalKey.
  Building a Coder using a registered CoderProvider failed.
  See suppressed exceptions for detailed failures.
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.CoderRegistry.getCoderFromFactories(CoderRegistry.java:693)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.CoderRegistry.getCoderFromTypeDescriptor(CoderRegistry.java:622)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.CoderRegistry.getCoder(CoderRegistry.java:254)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.CoderRegistry.getCoder(CoderRegistry.java:245)
    at com.example.BeanSerdeTestPipeline.main(BeanSerdeTestPipeline.java:26)
```

To demonstrate that I did use the `@DefaultSchema` and `@SchemaCreate` annotations properly, I manually registered a `SchemaCoder` using schema inferred from the schema annotations, and it ran fine:

```java
  public static void main(String[] args) throws CannotProvideCoderException, NoSuchSchemaException, IOException {
    PipelineOptions pipelineOptions = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();
    pipelineOptions.setRunner(DirectRunner.class);
    Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(pipelineOptions);
    CoderRegistry coderRegistry = pipeline.getCoderRegistry();
    SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry = pipeline.getSchemaRegistry();
    coderRegistry.registerCoderForClass(TemporalKey.class, schemaRegistry.getSchemaCoder(TemporalKey.class));
    Coder<TemporalKey> temporalKeyCoder = coderRegistry.getCoder(TemporalKey.class);
    System.out.println(temporalKeyCoder.getClass());

    temporalKeyCoder.encode(new TemporalKey(2021, 1, 1, 0), System.out);
  }

  /**
   * Output:
   * class org.apache.beam.sdk.schemas.SchemaCoder
   * And the invocation of the encode() method did not throw any error
   */
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that with `@DefaultSchema(JavaBeanSchema.class)` a coder for provided Bean class will be initiated and added automatically to Schema registry in runtime, only when you run your pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This issue actually originated from one of my pipeline runs where it did not pickup the coders for my `@DefaultSchema` annotated class.

Comment: Could you share a code snippet to reproduce that issue?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanenko code snippet at the end of the original post demonstrates the issue but I believe a similar issue with sample code was reported in Github.  https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/29577